# How to add a Custom Annotation using ASM

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation

I have a Java Class which i wish to enhance to add my custom annotation when the files are compiled. I found [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html) provides Bytecode Manipulation when the files are compiled. I saw that it can be used to add fields and methods, however can it be used to add a custom Annotation whose retention is Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to do the following:

- Load ClassNode for your class file
- Find MethodNode which corresponds to the method which you want to add annotation to and add it
- Write ClassNode back with ClassWriter

This should do the job.